# Locale settings and currency formatting

Tags: web, locale

I'm asking this as a programming question because it's something developers encounter every day. It may not be a hard/hands-on practical coding question.

So, here's the situation.
Usually, a price in US dollars will be formatted with US dollar symbol on the left of the amount i.e: $20.32

What I'd like to know - if a user comes to my website which formats currencies based on user's locale, will this format change?
I.e. if a user with locale de_de visits my website, will he see the price in format 20.32 $ ?
What I'm asking is - is this ok or should I force prices in USD to use $XX formatting?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Something else that you may want to consider is that US dollarsare not the only currency that uses the $ symbol, so you should probably force formatting to include US$xx formatting or state that all prices are in US Dollar amounts, unless you are dynamically recalculating the price using FOREX conversions appropriately to the users locale, so that there is no doubt that you mean US Dollars.